# Position Page.Header.Header.Controls.Add

Tags: asp.net, controls, master-pages

How do i position a collection of Page.Header.Header.Controls.Add that i have. So, i want them to appear right after the head tag. The code behind loads more controls into the head, so currently the order of all controls is net very logic. Css, javascript and meta are randomly positioned between the head tags.

Example:

```
    Dim ogtitle As New HtmlMeta
    ogtitle.Name = "og:title"
    ogtitle.Content = sMetaTitle
    Page.Header.Controls.Add(ogtitle)
```

I want to make sure it is right after the head/title tag (position 1 so to say):

```
   <head runat="server">
   <title></title>
   <meta property="og:title" content="The Rock" />
```

Is there a property that can be added to Page.Header.Header.Controls.Add to position it?

Thanks in advance!

Marcellino

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using 'AddAt'.  For example:

```
Page.Header.Controls.AddAt(2, ogtitle)
```

I hope that helps.

Karl